# How the state machine describes the dynamic behaviour of use cases

Tags: uml, behavior, use-case, state-diagram

As I read through UML reference Manual chapter 7,state machine view ,page 81:

`the state machine describes the dynamic behaviour of use cases`

Could you Please illustrate the above quoted sentence through simple example ?

Answer (score 1):

A Simple example based on login, the usecase are the triggers for the state transitions.

[image]

Comment: thank you @Martin,what about guard condition and effect for each event in your example?

Comment: What about guard conditions?  They are simple discrete conditions.  What is important is the trigger events and those should be quite obvious given the example.  valid(userName,password) == true;